# Наибольшая сумма цифр в веденных числах

Tags: c++

При вводе 0 необходимо вывести наибольшую сумму из цифр в введенных числах и само это число.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

long long n;
long long max=0;

int suma_cyfr(long long n)
{
    if (n>0)
        return n % 10 + suma_cyfr(n / 10);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    do{
        cout << "wwedi chislo naturalnoe: ";
        cin >> n;
    if (n < 0)
        do  
        {
            cout << "Eto otricatelnoe chislo/n Podaj polozitelnoe ";
            cin >> n;
        } while (n < 0); 
        cout << "Suma cyfr  " << n << " sostowliaet " << suma_cyfr(n) << endl;
    } while (n!=0 );  
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: уточните, наибольшую сумму из скольких чисел?двух, трех, десяти?всех?

Comment: А что мешает искать максимум и запоминать соответствующую ему переменную сразу перед `while (n != 0)` и печатать их сразу после?

Comment: если нужно наибольшее сумма чисел, зачем тогда `suma_cyfr(n)` и если вы не берете отрицательный, то сумма всегда наибольшая

Comment: Чисел может быть неограниченное число

Comment: Максимум с введеных чисел?

Comment: так сумму скольких чисел считать то?

Comment: всех введенных. точное число не задано

Comment: @Александр, считать нужно сумму **цифр** (из них состоит число) каждого введенного положительного числа. А потом надо напечатать максимальную из этих сумм и соответствующее ей число.

Comment: @Александр  да, верно

Comment: сразу бы так и написали

Comment: @Александр :) хорошо

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Да вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 0;
    int max_sum = 0;
    int number_with_max_sum = 0;
    do 
    {
        cout << "Введите натуральное число\n";
        cin >> n;

        if (n < 0) {
            cout << "Я просил натуральное\n";
            continue;
        }
        int sum = suma_cyfr(n);
        if (sum > max_sum) {
            max_sum = sum;
            number_with_max_sum = n;
        }
    } while (n != 0);
    cout << "Максимальная сумма цифр: " << max_sum
         << ", для числа " << number_with_max_sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь